# How do I comment out a block of javascript code mixed with server tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, visual-studio, comments

Say I have this piece of javascript/jQuery code and I want to comment out the marked code block.

```
<script>

function checkValues() {
    // Important function
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".item").click(function () {
        // Important action
    });

    /* I want to comment this block out, from here...
     $("#<%=Application("InstID")%>").blur(function () {

     });
     $("#<%=Application("ComID")%>").blur(function () {

     });
    ...to here */    
});
</script>
```

But the server tags won't allow a regular comment block with `/* comment */`. Is there another way to make a code block in this case?

Visual studio won't recognize the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> either.

Comment: Use server side comments

Comment: I think `<%=` statement will be parsed by asp.net by anyhow :)

Comment: The comment you have should work fine. The fact there is server-side values written to the response should make no difference

Comment: Beware of the server tags. They always gets parsed even if it is commented. Once I tried doing a session clear code in script block and realised later that it was done when the page was parsed not when click happened. I commented the code and found still the session was being cleared. Later realised, the server tags gets rendered any how. Just delete them :)

Comment: If <%= tags are parsed inside <%-- then you are using a brain dead programming language. If the IDE greys out the code inside the tags, you should expect the code not to be parsed ever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can wrap them with the comment block of `<%-- --%>`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".item").click(function () {
        // Important action
    });

    <%--
    $("#<%=Application("InstID")%>").blur(function () {

    });
    $("#<%=Application("ComID")%>").blur(function () {

    });
    --%>
});
```

Comment: If you move on to MVC with Razor, it has a similar concept of `@* commented out stuff goes here *@`